# Nodejs: ¿Cómo formatear texto con lenguaje natural desde Backend?

Tags: nodejs, inteligencia-artificial, nlp, openapi, gpt

Tengo una pregunta, me gustaría recibir sus consejos y sugerencias. Se que este es el mejor lugar para obtenerlo.

Estoy realizando un bot desde el backend, en nodeJS Express, para el BOT utilizo Cognitive y GPT. La primera se encarga de buscar en mi base de conocimientos la respuesta más próxima a la consulta y GPT recibe esa respuesta como contexto para formular la respuesta final que recibirá el usuario en lenguaje natural en base a la consulta de este y el contexto.

Hasta alli me funciona bastante bien, las cosas se empiezan a complicar cuando quiero lograr adjuntar imágenes a la respuesta generada por GPT. Como saben, GPT es una IA del tipo "procesador de texto" entonces no puedo hacer que genere imágenes, sin embargo, si puedo idear técnicas para realizar mi objetivo.

De mi base de conocimientos yo obtengo algo como lo siguiente (es un ejemplo)

> Para realizar ventas en  App, debe de irse a la sección Ventas. Seleccionar los productos que desea agregar al carrito, dando clic sobre cada producto, así se agregan y visualizan en la lista. Luego, dar clic en el botón  *Cobrar"* para continuar con el proceso de pago. {{IMG1}} Escoger el método de pago. {{IMG2}} Ingresar o seleccionar el monto a pagar y dar clic en el botón  *Cobrar*  {{IMG3}} Nos muestra una previsualización de la comanda para imprimir y enviar al área de cocina. {{IMG4}} Después de imprimir la comanda nos muestra la pantalla para generar la factura con cualquiera de las tres opciones. Luego dar clic en  *Nueva venta*  para salir. {{IMG5}} En caso de cobrar un pedido, se debe ir a la sección de historial donde aparecen los pedidos guardados. {{IMG6}} En los pedidos completados, damos clic sobre el pedido y le damos clic en el botón  *Cobrar* . {{IMG7}} Escoger el método de pago y el tipo de pedido. {{IMG8}} Elegir el monto con el que se va a pagar. {{IMG9}} Listo, se ha realizado el cobro del pedido exitosamente. Dar clic en  *Nueva Venta*  para finalizar. {{IMG10}} Para ver el funcionamiento como tal, de cómo generar una venta, App dispone de videos como el siguiente. ¿Cómo realizar una venta y cobrar con efectivo? {{VIDEO1}}

Como ven tengo diferentes etiquetas como {{IMG}} y {{VIDEO}}. Lo que queria lograr con GPT es que en la respuesta que generara "respetara" el formato que yo tengo en mi texto original, de esa forma luego solo formatearia el texto y prodria remplazar esas "etiquetas" y hacer uso de ellas segun mi caso de uso. Pero yo no puedo controlar la forma en que GPT genera sus respuestas, si bien puede agregar las etiquetas las puede ignorar

Asi que ese es mi problema al final yo quisiera poder retornar algo como lo siguiente:

> Para realizar una venta en App puedes seguir los siguientes pasos:

\n1. Selecciona los productos a agregar al carrito. Luego dar clic al botón *Cobrar* {{IMG1}}\n

\n2. Seleccione el método de pago. {{IMG2}}\n

\n3. Seleccione el monto a pagar y de clic en el botón  *Cobrar.*  {{IMG3}}\n

\n4. Seleccione el monto a pagar y de clic en el botón  *Cobrar.*  {{IMG3}}\n

\n5. Le mostrará un vista previa para imprimir {{IMG4}}\n

\n6. Después de imprimir le mostrará la pantalla para generar la factura con cualquiera de las tres opciones. Luego dar clic en  *Nueva venta*  para salir. {{IMG5}}

\n7. Seleccione el método de pago y el tipo de pedido. {{IMG8}}

\n8. Seleccione el monto con el que pagará. {{IMG9}}

\n9. La venta se ha realizado exitosamente. {{IMG10}}

¡Y listo! Has creado una nueva venta, si tiene alguna otra consulta no dude en preguntar. Estoy aquí para ayudarte. También puedes visitar el {{VIDEO1}} si algo no quedo claro sobre como realizar una venta en App.

Pero no se que herramientas de las tantas que encuentras en una busqueda general en Google o que tecnicas utilizar para alcanzar mi objetivo, probe DialogFlow pero lamentablemente la informacion no esta estructurada de forma que pueda aprovecharlo, probe tensorflow, incluso probe natural-nlp, pero no llego a una solución, por supuesto que se que podría ser por el hecho de que para mi la IA es una tecnologia con la que apenas estoy comenzando.

Por eso estoy aqui, porque me gustaria recibir ideas, incluso un blog adjunto en cualquier idioma que hable del tema, una solucion para aprender y quien sabe tambien para compartir con aquellos en el futuro que esten tan perdidos como lo estoy yo en este momento.

Les comparto un poco de mi codigo, les agradezco de antemano cualquier tipo de ayuda, en este punto necesito ayuda y estaré realmente agradecida

```
export async function askOpenAI(query: string) {

    const system = "";
    const responseFromCognitiveSearch: CognitiveModelRequest = await searchInCognitiveWithRequest(query);
    const prompt = stripIndent`${oneLine`
    ¡Usted es un representante de App que es muy útil cuando se trata de hablar sobre cualquier tema! Tiene conocimientos amplios 
    de App y sus aplicaciones. No tienes limites en temas, tienes conocimientos de App como de cualquier otro tema. Solo responda sinceramente y ¡sea tan útil como pueda! 
    Si necesita hacer otra pregunta para aclarar la consulta del usuario hagala. Cuando la consulta sea sobre App, siempre mencioneló en sus respuestas.
    Si no esta seguro de la respuesta realice una pregunta al usuario que pueda ayudarle a comprender la consulta."`}
    Secciones de contexto:
    ${responseFromCognitiveSearch.value[0].description}
    Pregunta: """
    ${query}
    """
    Respuesta:`;
  
    const requestOpenAI: ResponseModelTurboGPT = await openAiStreamPrompt(system, prompt);
    const answerOpenAI: string = requestOpenAI.choices[0].message.content;
  
    return answerOpenAI
  }

 export const openAiStreamPrompt = async (system: string, prompt: string) => {

    // https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions
    const start = Date.now();
    const apiKey = TOKEN_OPEN_AI;
    const url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
    const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
    };


    const data = {
        "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        "messages": [
            {
                "role": "system",
                "content": system
            },
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": prompt
            }
        ],
        "temperature": 0.7,
        "n": 1,
        "stop": null
    };

    const res = await axios.post(url, data, { headers: headers });

    const end = Date.now();
    const elapsed = end - start;
    // const answer = response?.data.choices[0].message.content.trim() ?? "Ops, Lo siento! No puedo responderte actualmente, intentalo más tarde.";
    console.log(`Response time was ${elapsed}ms, sending delayed message`);

    console.log('res', res.data);

    return res.data

}
```